# The modulo 6 of primes at certain distances from another prime

Tags: number-theory, symmetry, prime-gaps

While doing some statistics on primes pairs for a given gap between them, I noticed this phenomenon:

For each $p$ prime $\ge 7$ and all $q$ prime $> 6p$ such that $(q - 4p)$ is prime, we have the same value for ${q\!\! \mod\!6}$   (either only $1$ or only $5$).

I have verified it through calculations for $p$ between $7$ and $7919$ and for around $1200$ first $q$ values for each $p$.

I am not sure if the above conjecture is true and how hard it is to prove it, can you number theorists take a stab at it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Same value as what?  Every prime $> 3$ is $\equiv \pm1 \pmod 6\ $ so you don't need any further hypotheses to deduce that.

Comment: @BillDubuque : all q mod 6 = 1 or all q mod 6 = -1.

Comment: I meant: q mod 6 does not change (it either stays 1 or -1) , for all q values in the conditions mentioned in the original post.

Comment: All q primes >= 43 with q - 28 prime have q mod 6 = -1 (I have taken p = 7 in my original post).

Comment: Because, necessarily $\bmod 6\!:\,\ q\equiv -p\equiv -7\equiv -1\,$ as I explain in my answer. This is true not only for *primes* $> 3$ but for any *coprimes* to $6.\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

All primes $>3$ are either $\pm 1 \pmod 6$.  Let's go case by case.

First, assume $p\equiv 1 \pmod 6$.  Then we have $$q-4p\equiv q-4\pmod 6$$  In that case it is not possible for $q\equiv 1\pmod 6$ as that would give  $$1-4\equiv 3\pmod 6$$  And the "prime" would be divisible by $3$.

Similarly, $$p\equiv -1 \pmod 6\implies q-4p=q+4\pmod 6$$ and here we can't have $q\equiv -1 \pmod 6$ for the same reason, and we are done.

Comment: And it works not only for *primes* $> 3$ but also for any *coprimes* to $\,6,\,$ as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's the direction $(\Rightarrow)$ below in the special case: $\,p,\,q,\,p\!-\!4q\,$ are all primes $ > 3.$

**Lemma** $\ $ If $\ (p,6)=1=(q,6)\ $ then $\ (p\!-\!4q,6)=1\iff q \equiv -p\pmod{\! 6}$

**Proof $\bf\, 1$** $\bmod 6\!:\ p\!-\!4q \equiv (p/q\!+\!2)q\,$ is invertible if $\,p/q = -1,\,$ not if $\,p/q\equiv 1$

**Proof $\bf\, 2$** $\,\ p,q\,$ coprime to $\,6\,\Rightarrow\,\bmod 6\!:\,\ p,q\equiv \pm1,\,$ so either $\,\color{#c00}{q\equiv -p}\,$ therefore $\, (p\!-\!4\color{#c00}q,\,6) = (5p,6)=(-p,6)=1,\, $ else $\ \color{#0a0}{q\equiv p}\,$ so $\,(p\!-\!4\color{#0a0}q,\,6) = (-3p,6)\neq 1$

Comment: We used $\,\large \ (a,6) = (b,6)\ $ if $\ \large a\equiv b\pmod{\!6}\ $ by Euclid.

Comment: It remains true if we replace $\,p-4q\,$  by $\,p+2q\,$ since they are congruent $\!\bmod 6\ \ $